# Struggling from or struggling with?

Tags: grammaticality

Why is the sentence "She is struggling **from** an illness" incorrect?
I know the correct sentence is "She is struggling **with** an illness", but  "struggling from" just sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

This expression has more inspiring context behind. *"Struggling with illness"* sounds like you're strong enough to fight and win while *"struggling from smth"* associates with the action when you're trying to fend off.
But this is just my opinion.

E.g.: Footballers struggle with injuries.

Footballers struggle from poor form.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion based upon my research,"struggle" can be used as verb or noun. Now, I am explaining usage of "struggle" as 'verb' in detail:

Usage of "struggle" as verb:

1.a) struggle + (for something): It means to try very hard to do something when it is difficult or when there are a lot of problems.
e.g, a country struggling for independence. Here, struggle is coming
    with 'for' + 'something' is independence.

1.b) struggle + (adverb/preposition): to move somewhere or do something with difficulty.    e.g, He struggled out of his wheelchair.

1.c) struggle + (against/with somebody/something): to fight against somebody or something in order to prevent a bad situation or result. e.g, He struggled against cancer for two years. OR She is struggling with an illness.[Your Query's Answer is 'struggle' + 'with' + 'something']

1.d) struggle + (with somebody): to fight somebody or try to get away from them. e.g, Tim was hit in the mouth as he struggle with the enemies.

1.e) struggle + (with somebody) + (for something): to compete or argue with somebody, especially in order to get something. e.g, I am struggling with my neighbours for my property.

If you need the usage for "struggle" as a noun, I can do it.